# STM32 - How to trigger interrupt after a certain PWM ON time?

Tags: timer, stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4, stm32-hal

I'm new to ARM MCUs (STM32F411), and I have been trying to find my way around the peripherals using STM's HAL library and STM32Cube.

I've already configured my board in order to use some peripherals:

- **Timer 2** for running an interrupt with a certain frequency
- **Timer 3** for running PWMs on 3 channels of it.
- **ADC** with 4 channels, into DMA mode, for reading some analog input.

Let us suppose, now, that the PWM's whole period is *100 ms* and its  duty cycle is 50% (*50 ms* PWM on and *50 ms* PWM off).

I would like to trigger an interrupt after a certain time of the PWM on level, let us say 50% of it.

**Hence, I would like to run an interrupt at 25 ms in order to use the ADC for sampling it's analog inputs.**

Do you have any suggestion on how could I implement such a kind of interrupt?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You could start another timer at the begining of the PWM periods, which will generate an interrupt after 25 ms.

Comment: Does STM32F4 have a functionality which lets me do such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the ADC of the STM32F411 is used in Regular mode (**not** Injected mode) and only three channels out of four are used to generate PWM on Timer 3, the fourth channel can be used to trigger the ADC.

Hence Timer 3 is configured as follows:

- **CH1** used for ***Output Compare mode 0*** (TIM3->CCMR1.OC1M = 0)
- **CH2**, **CH3**, **CH4** used for **PWM outputs**

Therefore **TIM3->CCR1** is loaded to a value that gives 25% of duty, then it will generate TIM3_CH1 events that can be used to trigger ADC start-of-conversion at 25% of your TIM3 timebase.